# Массив структуры

Tags: c++, массивы, структуры

Разработайте структуру для хранения данных о цветном кружке:

К примеру вот структура:

```
struct Krug {
    char cvetKr;
    int x, y, z;
};
```

передаю в функцию структуру.

```
 int N = 3; //количество кружков  
 Krug* globalKrug = nullptr;  
 EnterKrug(globalKrug, N);
```

по идее надо сделать: *"Создайте массив цветных кружков"*.

вот функция. Тут я не правильно принимаю как-то структуру.

```
void EnterKrug(Krug *globalKrug, int NN)
{
    for(int i=0; i<=NN; i++)
    {
        scanf(&(globalKrug)[i].cvetKr);
    }
}
```

Comment: Не понятен смысл вопроса. Что у вас не получается? Представьте минимальный проверяемый пример кода.

Comment: не получается правильно создать массив гружков. примера проверяемого нет. Не знаю чем. Но поидее должны появится N кружков со своими параметрами

Answer (score 3):

В C++ вы можете создать массив, явно объявив его, как, например,

```
const size_t N = 3;//количество кружков  
^^^^^
Krug globalKrug[N];
```

Или распределить его в динамической памяти. Например,

```
size_t N = 3;//количество кружков  
Krug *globalKrug = new Krug[N];
```

Имейте в виду, что данное предложение в функции

```
scanf(&(globalKrug)[i].cvetKr);
```

некорректное. Вы должны по крайней мере записать

```
scanf( " %c", &globalKrug[i].cvetKr );
       ^^^^^
```

Answer (score 3):

Помимо того, что вы не выделяете память (об этом написал [@Vlad from Moscow](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/183394/vlad-from-moscow)), у вас есть еще одна нестыковка:

```
int N = 3;//количество кружков
```

А тут вы пишете

```
for(int i=0; i<=NN; i++)
```

В результате цикл выполняется `N+1` раз.

Comment: ну это я бы потом обнаружил, спасибо, сама проблема в правильном вызове функции, не могу понять эти указатели и ссылки и динамический массив